# CakePHP 2 Bake unable to create a Model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2, cakephp-bake

I am trying to create a model through Cake Bake command. 
I am using windows and II7. I have set up the global variables on the system path so i can do "cake bake" on my Command Prompt.

I have my database config defined in App/config/database.php

Once i do it, i press M for Model, then i select the default database and the console shows this message:

```
Your database does not have any tables.
```

And i am not able to create any model for my project.

If i manually create a table on my DB, the error changes and it shows this: http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-picture-8000920.html

What's the problem with it? Of course i have no tables if i have just installed Cake!!

Comment: You can not create tables from a Model with Bake. The Model must be created from tables, so for that you need the whole database created first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create your tables with, let's say, **phpMyAdmin** (localhost/phpmyadmin).

Then, if you have properly configured your database configuration in **app/config/database.php** you will see Models in your Bake script you can create.

Answer (score 1):

refer below links to get step by step methodology in cake bake

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html
http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/baking_with_cakephp

you can also check environment variable settings for this error